# Enigmatic NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, textview

I'm getting the following Null Pointer Exception. Whenever I click on the button(which i've an intent to launch) . i get a FC and this nullpointer exception. Could it be because of the use of that text file?

## Logcat

```
    04-25 20:02:40.762: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(29671): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
    04-25 20:02:40.772: D/memalloc(29671): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x514e1000 size:3649536 offset:3035136 fd:56
    04-25 20:02:40.982: D/memalloc(29671): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51b08000 size:4325376 offset:3710976 fd:59
    04-25 20:02:41.632: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(29671): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
    04-25 20:02:41.632: D/memalloc(29671): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5212e000 size:4939776 offset:4325376 fd:62
    04-25 20:02:41.692: D/memalloc(29671): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52615000 size:5554176 offset:4939776 fd:68
    04-25 20:02:41.712: D/memalloc(29671): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x514e1000 size:3649536 offset:3035136
    04-25 20:02:41.712: D/memalloc(29671): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51b08000 size:4325376 offset:3710976
    04-25 20:02:42.842: D/memalloc(29671): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x513e1000 size:4325376 offset:3710976 fd:53
    04-25 20:02:42.882: W/dalvikvm(29671): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dbb9d8)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dreamgoogle.gihf/com.dreamgoogle.gihf.Stories}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1884)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1965)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at com.dreamgoogle.gihf.Stories.<init>(Stories.java:14)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1025)
    04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1875)
```

## xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jobsdes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/sj1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Java File.

```
    public class Stories extends Activity {
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobsdes);
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_stories);
            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
            ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
            myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    
            t1.setText(R.raw.jobs);
    
        }
    
        private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
            public int getCount() {
                return 4;
            }
    
            public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                int resId = 0;
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    resId = R.layout.activity_stories;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    resId = R.layout.sto2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    resId = R.layout.sto3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    resId = R.layout.sto4;
                    break;
                }
                View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                return view;
            }
    
            public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
                ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
            }
    
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
            }
    
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                return null;
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

here's the pager xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Stories" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the TextView after setcontentview and that'll do it.

Answer (score 4):

Exception

> 04-25 20:02:42.902: E/AndroidRuntime(29671): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-25 20:02:42.902:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29671):    at
>   android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1965)

Code

```
findViewById(R.id.pager1)
```

XML

```
android:id="@+id/jobsdes"
```

i would say, your findViewbyId returns zero

Comment: No. I have that Textview with that resource id.

Comment: so you need to setContentView(R.layout.pager ); befor can find the element. ( as TronicZomB has described)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find the `TextView` before it is even in the activity:

```
public class Stories extends Activity {
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobsdes); //RIGHT HERE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stories);
```

You need to find it after `setContentView`, like this:

```
public class Stories extends Activity {
    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stories);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.josdes);
```

Comment: Agree with your findings. Also noticing that `R.id.pager1` is not in the xml posted. That will also lead to a `null` object being returned.

Comment: That solved the purpose. Can you tell me why is it that you have to do that after set content view?

Comment: @StevenByle agreed. I didn't notice that one until MemLeak pinted it out. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using different xml(s) for a swipe view. The pager is in another xml.

Comment: @user2320244 it is because the layout xml file has not yet been attached/associated with the activity. You have to set the view and then the activity will be able to find the item using `findViewById`.

Comment: @StevenByle correct me if I am wrong in the above comment please.

Comment: In the myPager adapter I already attached the layout file with it. See ,R.layout.sto2.xml

Comment: But, the issue is still the same.

Comment: @user2320244 So what you are saying is that the `R.id.pager1` is not causing any null problems? So then this should be all that you need to do to solve the problem... correct? Are you having any other problems?

Comment: Yep! Pager1 is just fine. The problem is with that the logcat says " Failed to instantiate activity, null pointer exception. "

Comment: @user2320244 but did my answer fix the null pointer exception or is it still there?

Comment: @user2320244 the log cat error should give a line number as to where the NPE is, check that line and I am guessing it is due to the `R.id.pager1` because you are associating the `TextView` layout with this activity but you are trying to reference a item that is in a different xml that is not associated with the activity. You will need to move your `ViewPager` to the same xml that is being associated with this activity in order to reference it.